# Is druid suitable for dimension base data

Tags: druid

I have data which are all string so its prefer as dimension.
But i want to run group-by query for yearly ,monthly and daily data for count of specific dimension.

My system generate per hour around 5cr data.

Is it good to use druid. Is there any other suitable data base available for this type of no-SQL data ?
Or 
if good use druid than how should be schema structure and approach ?

Answer (score 0):

Druid is a multi dimension for filters and aggregate data. In your case, It good to use druid but please concern that define appropriate schema is needed. If you want to filter on age that is the dimension contains age, and if you want to count on impression that is the metric contains impression. You must specific it on your schema as well as be careful in design it. 
The concern to druid is time for query on datasource just sub-second, but time of ingestion data to it is time-consuming process. It require the cluster configuration. When you put data to it, you cannot update the values in dimension or metric to ingested datasource